# Create a date/hour table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, lookup-tables

I basically need to create a table that looks like the below

```
Date        |       Hour 
01-01-2016  |        0
01-01-2016  |        1
01-01-2016  |        2
01-01-2016  |        3
```

And so on, for every date from 01-01-2016 up until yesterdays date. It would consist of a date column, and 24 rows per date for each hour.

What's the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a CTE to generate one row for each hour:

```
; with  cte as
        (
        select  cast('2016-01-01' as datetime) as dt
        union all
        select  dateadd(hour, 1, dt)
        from    cte
        where   dateadd(hour, 1, dt) < cast(getdate() as date)
        )
insert  into YourTable
        (date, hour)
select  cast(dt as date)
,       datepart(hour, dt)
from    cte
order by
        dt desc
option  (maxrecursion 0)
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/db88c/1/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
Create table #temp
(
  DATE1 DATE,
  HOUR INT
);
DECLARE @inc INT
SET @inc = 0
DECLARE @start_date date
SET @start_date = '01-01-2016'
DECLARE @end_date date
SET @end_date = DATEADD (day , -1 , getdate() )
WHILE @start_date<=@end_date
    BEGIN
        IF(@inc <=23)
          BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #temp SELECT @start_date As Date,@inc As Hour
            SET @inc = @inc+1
          END
        ELSE
          BEGIN
            SET @inc = 0
            SET @start_date = DATEADD (day , 1 , @start_date )
          END
    END; 
SELECT * FROM #temp;
```

Live Demo

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6727a/4
>
> http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6b6ac4e15b1a262275a6797e48d5c741

Answer (score -1):

**Try This In MySQL:**

```
create table tablename(date Date,hour number);


insert into tablename(date,hour)values(SUBSTRING(NOW(),1,10),SUBSTRING(NOW(),12,2));
```

**Explanation:**
`NOW()` returns the whole date in `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` .......so the first time `substring()` method is used it get the date from NOW method and second time `substring` method is called it returns the hour. :)

Comment: Put the Above queries in python and write a program so that they trigger  for every one hour